# QGIS Distance to nearest hub wrong point selection for distance calulation

Tags: qgis, distance, qgis-modeler, unique-id

I'm using the graphical modeler in QGIS 3.28.8 to automatically calculate distances of two lines between points, see the picture.

[image]

To do this, I'm using `Distance to nearest hub (line to hub)` and an attribute from the line I want to measure in the `Hub layer name attribute`. Somehow the second line (green) always measures the distance of the first, presumably because both line layers share the `fid` attribute. How can I make it so that `Distance to nearest hub (line to hub)` calculates the correct distance?

I've tried removing the `fid` in the first layer and also adding a unique ID for the second line layer, both result in `Error encountered while running Distance to nearest hub (line to hub)`

Here's the model I'm using with basic commentary for some context:
[image]

Comment: As input of line intersections I think you have one projected layer and the other isn't projected. Try to change the input that's not projected to the the projected layer that's generated generated in the second step of your model.

Comment: @Mayo Thanks for you suggestion. I tried it but it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Are "Detected trees" and "Real tree points" in the same projection?

Comment: @Mayo Yes they are